# HTML5 Canvas Transparent Stroke on Custom Shape

Tags: html5-canvas, transparency, stroke

I am new to HTML5 Canvas, and have searched a few top sites and other questions here about this issue I am having.  All I am wanting to do create a clear 0 pixel stroke on this custom shape cloud I am practicing with.

But is this possible?  With my current codes, my cloud has a mini black outline in Google Chrome.
How do I fix this?

```
 <canvas id="myCanvas" width="578" height="200"></canvas>
 <script>
  var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

  // begin custom shape
  context.beginPath();
  context.moveTo(170, 80);
  context.bezierCurveTo(130, 100, 130, 150, 230, 150);
  context.bezierCurveTo(250, 180, 320, 180, 340, 150);
  context.bezierCurveTo(420, 150, 420, 120, 390, 100);
  context.bezierCurveTo(430, 40, 370, 30, 340, 50);
  context.bezierCurveTo(320, 5, 250, 20, 250, 50);
  context.bezierCurveTo(200, 5, 150, 20, 170, 80);

 // complete custom shape
  context.closePath();
  context.lineWidth = 0;
  context.fillStyle = 'pink';
  context.fill();
  context.strokeStyle = 'none';
  context.stroke();
  </script>
```

Comment: What would such a stroke do? I mean, just remove `stroke()` if you want no stroke.

Comment: // complete custom shape
    context.closePath();
    context.lineWidth = 0;
    context.fillStyle = 'pink';
    context.fill();
    context.strokeStyle = 'none';
    context.stroke();
    </script>

This works!  Thank you. :)  I swore I tried this earlier, but I guess the Google Drive HTML editor apps I was using weren't loading my edits well.  Sometimes there is a delay in displaying updated codes.

Comment: Sorry.  I don't know how to get that code to format properly...